# Attempted "__set__" operation on ASN.1 schema object

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I'm currently using IronPython to execute Python code in my .NET project. The issue, however, is that I am receiving an error:

```
Attempted "__set__" operation on ASN.1 schema object
```

This is the C# code:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
//var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
///searchPaths.Add(@"PATH_TO_FILE");
//searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages");
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("PATH_TO_FILE");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("startAt", "2019-05-20");
source.Execute(scope);
```

I created a basic script and tested again. The script executes fine, so it seems the issue is with the Python code. I can't link the rest here, however, since a lot of it is API based and requires a lot of setup to get working.

```
import sys

def main(argv):
    print("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I was hoping if someone has run into this issue before. I researched online and didn't find many matches.

Comment: Oddly enough, I found [this](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ubzrnGL3cDkJ:https://catsoop.mit.edu/repocat-soop/rev/22343ad09ba3d1c4cd090d043690bca138efe17f+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), which contains the line of code `raise error.PyAsn1Error('Attempted "%s" operation on ASN.1 schema object' % attr' % name)`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Interesting. I wonder why this is being thrown at all given that he Python script runs just fine on its own.